# Rewrite rules for custom CMS

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm in the process of building a custom CMS for a client and I'm getting stuck on rewrite rules in .htaccess.  I'm trying to rewrite anything to page/?pid=xxx -- so, for example, /about becomes page/pid=123.

I assume the problem that I'm having is twofold: I'm building this site in a subdirectory for the time being (/clients/afsb) and I've also got an existing rewrite rule in place to remove the .php from file extensions.  Another possible wrinkle is that I'd like to be able to have the rewrite rule ignore any files that actually exist -- for example, the home page is at index.php (or just /, in this case) and I wouldn't want the rule to affect that.  Likewise I've got two other pages that are not dynamic (/contact, for example.)  Here's what I've tried in .htaccess for the time being:

```
<Files php.ini> 
  order allow,deny 
  deny from all 
</Files>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /clients/afsb

# Redirect to remove .php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Redirect to "page" for dynamic pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)/$ page?&pid=$1

<Files ~ "\.inc$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

I'm obviously not too strong with .htaccess or regex in general so I'd appreciate any direction you can give.  Thanks!

Comment: Your conversion from "/about" to "pid=xxx" isn't going to work because you need to convert what "about" is to your database (the "pid"). The point of rewriteconds is that they take what you type in the URL as being a unique set of data that you use to query your CMS to find the corresponding page whether it be a static page or dynamic from a database

Comment: exactly how would Apache know that `/about` should become `page?pid=123`? that's not exactly a simple transformation. Unless you're embedding a ton of rewriterules, one for every `pid` you've got, this is something you'd need to do in PHP e.g. `/about` -> `/page?pid=about`, or use  rewritemap

Comment: Perhaps I've got the wrong rewrite rule (which wouldn't be surprising.)  I thought the asterisk would indicate everything after the last slash in the base URL would become the friendly URL, which page.php would then lookup to write the content.  Here's what I was basing that on: http://moz.com/ugc/using-mod-rewrite-to-convert-dynamic-urls-to-seo-friendly-urls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, this is what I needed -- I was missing the caret.  Thanks to both for looking into it.

```
# Redirect to remove .php 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Redirect to "page" for dynamic pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page?pid=$1 [L]
```